# Process Crashes When Using Nest Within netcoreapp3.x Console Application

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest, .net-core-3.0

I have a ES 7.4 server running on a Windows 10 dev machine and I have a .net core 3.x console app I am testing with that calls IndexMany() on a NEST client (running on the same machine) and I either get 1) the following exception (see below), or 2) I get the same exception on the finalizer thread calling System.Threading.Overlapped.Free(NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlappedPtr) Once the issue occurs the process crashes.

I am using the latest release version of Nest 7.4.2 and my ES server is 7.4 running as a windows service. Using SingleNodeConnectionPool and all default connection settings. This occurs within a console app with netcoreapp3.1 or netcoreapp3 (have not tested 2.x).

---

```cs
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

   at System.Threading.Overlapped.Free(NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlappedPtr)

   at System.Threading.PreAllocatedOverlapped.System.Threading.IDeferredDisposable.OnFinalRelease(Boolean disposed)

   at System.Threading.DeferredDisposableLifetime`1.Dispose(T obj)

   at System.Threading.PreAllocatedOverlapped.Dispose()

   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.Dispose()

   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DisposeCachedTaskSocketAsyncEventArgs()

   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Dispose(Boolean disposing)

   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Dispose()

   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Close(Int32 timeout)

   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)

   at System.IO.Stream.Close()

   at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()

   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.Dispose(Boolean disposing)

   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.Dispose()

   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.EnsureReadAheadAndPollRead()

   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetOrReserveHttp11ConnectionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)

   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.Request[TResponse](RequestData requestData)

   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.CallElasticsearch[TResponse](RequestData requestData)

   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)

   at Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticLowLevelClient.DoRequest[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)

   at Nest.ElasticClient.DoRequest[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest p, IRequestParameters parameters, Action`1 forceConfiguration)

   at Nest.ElasticClient.Bulk(IBulkRequest request)

   at Nest.IndexManyExtensions.IndexMany[T](IElasticClient client, IEnumerable`1 objects, IndexName index)

   at Bond.Search.ElasticSearchRepository.Index[T](IEnumerable`1 objects, String index) in 

Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

   at System.Threading.Overlapped.Free(NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlappedPtr)

   at System.Threading.PreAllocatedOverlapped.System.Threading.IDeferredDisposable.OnFinalRelease(Boolean disposed)

   at System.Threading.DeferredDisposableLifetime`1.Dispose(T obj)

   at System.Threading.PreAllocatedOverlapped.Dispose()

   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.Dispose()

   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DisposeCachedTaskSocketAsyncEventArgs()

   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Dispose(Boolean disposing)

   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Dispose()

   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Close(Int32 timeout)

   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)

   at System.IO.Stream.Close()

   at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()

   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.Dispose(Boolean disposing)

   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.Dispose()

   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.EnsureReadAheadAndPollRead()

   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetOrReserveHttp11ConnectionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)

   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.Request[TResponse](RequestData requestData)

   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.CallElasticsearch[TResponse](RequestData requestData)

   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)

   at Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticLowLevelClient.DoRequest[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)

   at Nest.ElasticClient.DoRequest[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest p, IRequestParameters parameters, Action`1 forceConfiguration)

   at Nest.ElasticClient.Bulk(IBulkRequest request)

   at Nest.IndexManyExtensions.IndexMany[T](IElasticClient client, IEnumerable`1 objects, IndexName index)

   at Bond.Search.ElasticSearchRepository.Index[T](IEnumerable`1 objects, String index) in
```

Comment: Looks like exception comes from IndexMany method. Could you share how do you call it from your code?

Comment: Its called with an array of POCO objects and a string which is the index name. Given the stack its not how this method is being called that is the issue. I can call this method sometimes and it works and other times I get this stack/exception.

Comment: Would be great if you could enable debugging external source in your IDE, this way once pdb are installed exception from NEST should show exact line number where the problem is happening.